# How to insert clickable text into a JTextPane?

Tags: java, html, swing, jtextpane

I've been making a chat program for a few days now and I'm completely stumped on how to create a nice looking clickable text without the use of HTML. I tried to use HTML, but had extremely weird results (see below). So I am now just using 
basic text rather then text/html.

[image: clickable text with html]

My first attempt to add clickable text was to use `JTextPane`'s ability to insert `Component`s along with the text. It inserted and worked perfectly, but it was vertically offset and looked very bad. I tried to mess with `setAlignmentY`, but had no luck aligning the components with the text.

```
    JLabel l = new JLabel(test);
    l.setFont(this.getFont());
    l.setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
    l.setBackground(Color.RED); //Just so i could see it better for testing
    l.addMouseListener(new FakeMouseListener());
    this.insertComponent(l);
```

I'm using `JTextPane` and inserting text using `doc.insertString`. I skip lines using the systems line separator, so a single line can contain multiple `doc.insertString`s (Which is were I ran into trouble when attempting to use text/html).

Comment: Just as a quick note, you can embed a component in your text pane which holds the text and make that component answer to clicks (some listener model, depending on the component).

Comment: @user1803551 Yes that's what i tried already. The problem with that is the component is offset vertically and looks very bad. It works, just looks terrible.

Comment: Oh, `this` in the code is a `JTextPane`. What was bad with HTML then? Maybe you can post a picture of what you want it to look like, because I can't tell what you call "looks terrible".

Comment: The picture is the issue i had. Every time i inserted - rather then adding TO the current HTML element, it would create a new one and then for whatever reason center the text inserted. Very strange .

Comment: When inserting your label, were you inserting your components with thé insertComponent method or with thé classic add method ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out i put `setAlignmentY(0.85f);` for the JTextPane instead of the JLable.

If you have an offset component you're attempting to insert into JTextPane, mess around with it's Y alignment. 0.85f works for me.

Answer (score 3):

This inserts HTML without any alignment problems. I think ("think" because I don't have enough of your code to know) that you had issues because of `Document.insertString` while I use `HTMLEditorKit.insertHTML`.

```
public class Example extends JFrame {

    Example() {

        JEditorPane pane = new JEditorPane();
        pane.setEditable(false);
        pane.setContentType("text/html");
        HTMLDocument doc = (HTMLDocument) pane.getDocument();
        HTMLEditorKit editorKit = (HTMLEditorKit) pane.getEditorKit();

        try {
            editorKit.insertHTML(doc, doc.getLength(), "<a href=\"http://click.com\">clickable1</a>", 0, 0, null);
            editorKit.insertHTML(doc, doc.getLength(), "<a href=\"c2\">clickable2</a>", 0, 0, null);
            editorKit.insertHTML(doc, doc.getLength(), "<a href=\"c3\">clickable3</a>", 0, 0, null);
        } catch (BadLocationException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        pane.addHyperlinkListener(new HyperlinkListener() {
            
            @Override
            public void hyperlinkUpdate(HyperlinkEvent e) {

                if (e.getEventType() == HyperlinkEvent.EventType.ACTIVATED) {
                    System.out.println(e.getSourceElement());
                    if (e.getURL() != null)
                        System.out.println(e.getURL());
                    else
                        System.out.println(e.getDescription());
                    System.out.println("-----");
                }
            }
        });

        add(pane);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new Example();
    }
}
```

**Notes:**

- `setEditable(false)` must be called for this to work properly (probably there is some convoluted way to make it work otherwise).
- The `HyperlinkListener` is just to prove that the links work, along with some demonstration of how to get the link string (`getURL` will only work if the link is a valid URL).
- You don't need to set the cursor, with or without the `HyperlinkListener`.

Comment: Quick question before i attempt this: What would be the best method to insert regular text? It's a chat program so users may try to use HTML in chat.

Comment: @bob You mean a different component to which users will enter the chat that will be displayed in the text pane? I would use a `JTextArea` unless you want to be able to paste images directly into the input component.

Comment: Only problem with JTextArea is it doesn't support chat color. Which is why i switched to JTextPane basic Text.

Comment: @bob A chat program usually has the text component to which you type, and one which displays the conversation. Which are we talking about in your question and which in these comments?

Comment: @bob If you use a text area for user input, in what way do you want them to indicate that a text should be colored if not by using HTML tags? "*how would i properly translate it to basic HTML text*" would depend on how the user tells the program that the text should be styled (color, bold, link...).

Comment: I've already worked out a color translation method. And i just answered my own question by messing with the code a bit. I'll get back to you on whether or not the formatting is fixed